# Intuition on Gibbs measures

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, ising-model

I am (roughly) aware of the way Gibbs measures are used to solve physical systems (e.g. the Ising model). We can basically boil it down to pinpointing a Hamiltonian.

My question is, consider a system with Ising-reminiscent, cascading dynamics (like opinion formation). In that case, how would we define the energy of an arrangement? What would the temperature be?

In short, can we generalise the concepts that show up in Gibbs measures, and if so how?

I sincerely apologise if my question is non-sensical. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Many researchers are thinking about your question. I'm afraid that you will not get a good answer. That is the main reason for non-equilibrium statistical physics to be so hard. We can't even pinpoint a good measure. Think of it the other way around: If the dynamics of your system are Hamiltonian and if we know this Hamiltonian, then we know how to describe it's thermodynamic properties: use the Gibbs measure. The rest is often really hard because we don't really know what to do.

Comment: The words you typed made my day. 
So, as it goes with many other fields, the tricky part is actually finding the system's Hamiltonian? 
Or could it be that the idea of a Hamiltonian does not even apply in certain systems?
Why are you not posting this as a reply? Sound like an answer.
Could you suggest me a review paper\textbook on this topic?

Comment: There are situation when it is simply not possible to define a Hamiltonian in the first place. It may also happen that you know the Hamiltonian but your system is coupled to a non-termal bath (or two baths at different temperatures). Then Gibbs goes out of the window as well. Non-equilibrium physics is just much more diverse than equilibrium. There are no tools that can be applied in general.

Comment: I have more questions now, that are probably changing the nature of the initial one. I do not know how to proceed according to stackxchange regulations.

Comment: I did not post this as an answer because I am not answering your question. Moreover I would rather wait and see what people have to say before posting an answer saying that your question can't be answered. I am confident that there is no general answer, but I am curious to see if someone comes up some something smart ans specific. I'll wait a few days and post my comment as an answer then. About the reference: I can't think of anything right now. Sorry.

Comment: You should probably post this as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many researchers are thinking about this question. I'm afraid that there is no straightforward answer. That is the main reason for non-equilibrium statistical physics to be so hard. We can't even pinpoint a good measure. Think of it the other way around: If the dynamics of your system are Hamiltonian and if we know this Hamiltonian, then we know how to describe it's thermodynamic properties: use the Gibbs measure. The rest is often really hard because we don't really know what to do.

There are situation when it is not even possible to define a Hamiltonian in the first place. It may also happen that the Hamiltonian is known but the system is coupled to a non-termal bath (or two baths at different temperatures). Then Gibbs goes out of the window as well. Non-equilibrium physics is just much more diverse than equilibrium. There are no tools that can be applied in general.